# How the data will be encrypted Before passing into SQL server using .NET and decrypted to use in .NET applications

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

i have a customer table like this

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

I need to encrypt the data before passing into SQL Server and decrypt the same data to use in the .NET developed applications say windows forms , Asp.Net or even MVC applications .

i need  to transfer the data with encrypted fromat to and from my application and also in the database . I need to make the data secure both during the transfer and also while saving in the SQL server.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Do you want your data encrypted in transit to and from your application, or at rest in the data base, or both? What kind of attack are you hoping to resist by using encryption? Why do you have tags for both MySQL and sql server on your question? Please [edit] your question to carilfy.

Comment: Yes i need the answers to transfer the data encrypted in the transit to and from my application also in the database . I need to make the data secure both during the transfer and also while saving in the SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Arun,

I understand you want your data to be unencrtyped at the point where it is consumed by the user, but remain encrypted at all other points ? This is the same requirement normally used to handle passwords within a system, apart from passwords are often destructively encrypted.

This will create severe challenges for you. You will not be able to use any reporting tools or aggregate database queries, because you will need to decrypt your protected data whenever it is used, and the decryption will be an important security node within your system with as few implementations and access as possible.

Ultimately your data will need to undergo decryption at the point of use. The decryption must be based on "who the user is" - i.e. must be based on authority they gain via your other authentication proccesses - logins, machine whitelists, DNS, AD etc. etc. This means all your endpoint applications must be properly secured. This also means they must not be able to be compromised. So you must be using SSL for all communications. You must also have a bullet proof authentication mechanism for your application (just hashing the users passwords will not be good enough - you need multiple layers of seed and layered hashing algorithms). So unless you know how to do all of this, stick with an operating system authentication like Active Directory/Azure AD or some kind of Federated Identity based on SAML.

The principal here is that the data is encrypted as soon as possible from when the user types it in, and is never decrypted until it becomes physically visible to another authorised user. You dont need to care about SQL Server encryption etc. since it will never be decrypted until the user wants to see it - SQL Server will just see a list of bytes.

Pick an symmetric or PSK encryption algorithm of your choice - but on no account try to write one yourself. Use that algorithm to encrypt as soon as the user types it in, using a PSK/SK obtained from your central services (web service would be the best way) but only to authorised individuals (the web service must refuse to give a key to an unauthorised individual). Encrypt your data and store and handle it in the regular way. When you retrieve it, send it encrypted to the client application - and let the client application retrieve the neccessary decryption keys from the service and decrypt at point of use.

Rememeber the best crypt/decrypt alorithms will require a "seed" and this typically is different for every record in the database, and may derive from some other unencrypted values in the record in question. For instance a Seed for a password encryption/hash might be the ASCII value of the first letter of the users surname, or some eosoteric combination of hashes of other static data (like the record's GUID).

Again this prevents any bulk decryption attempts and makes the guessing of one decrypt key very limited to only the single record it pertains to. Of course it has the side effect of making your data almost completely unreadable throughout your application - which is what you seem to want to achieve, but might not realise the impact of.

Comment: Thanks Philliph , I got more inputs from your comment . I will try by picking up an  encryption algorithm to make enforce the data to be encrypted . your comments are very useful with granularity in the Encryption standards .